# How to push to a protected repo

Tags: git, github

There is a protected "Challenge" repo which is an empty RoR app template for a coding challenge.
To solve that coding challenge I've created a new app with a new git in the folder and made many commits in that repo.

To push my new app to the challenge protected repo, I cloned that challenge repo, created a new branch `git checkout -b my-solution`, copy-pasted my whole code to that folder and `push origin my-solution`.

The whole code did get to that protected folder inside a new branch, but I lost all of my commits that shows each step I made for solving the challenge (Probably because when I copy-pasted my code to the cloned challenge folder it was overwriting the .git folder).

Is there any way I can still push my code to `my-solution` brach without losing all of my repo history?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way I can still push my code to my-solution brach without losing all of my repo history?

If you keep copy-pasting your code, you cannot achieve this. This is because git takes the `diff` of your file and then stores the changes as a commit. Copying-pasting a file would not be interpreted the same way we interpret it. For git it will be interpreted as the creation of a new file and code was then written into it.

If you want to preserve your history, you can try cloning your original repo with the complete code as-is.

You can also bring in the original repo as a submodule. This will be done using `git submodule add <repo-url>`. This can be useful as git will now treat this repo as an actual separate git repo. You can update the repo's history using `git submodule update`

I hope that helps you. If it doesn't, feel free to comment :)

Best.

PS: if you want to avoid too much hassle or lack the time, you might want to go with the first method.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What does it mean "If you want to preserve your history, you can try cloning your original repo with the complete code as-is"? I've got my solution repo and the actual code-challenge protected repo. Which one should I clone?

Comment: clone your solution repo into the challenge protected repo.
if this solves your reply, please mark the quesion as answered

Comment: Yes how do I clone the repo into the challenge protected repo? Can you show which commands I should use please?

Comment: first go into the challenge repo directory, then do a `git clone <repo-url>`. The URL can be in terms of a normal folder in your system or a GitHub/BitBucket, etc. URL too.

Comment: I tried that, it creates a sub-module for my solution inside of the challenge protected repo. So it looks like a different file inside of that challenge repo. And when you click on that it sends you to the a different repo. Is there any way to do that the challenge repo will include all my solution files and all commits together without going to a different repo?

Comment: The different repo you go to must be the repo whose URL you provided. I suggest you do not use the submodule solution, instead simply clone your repo into the challenge repo.